# How do I connect android emulator to a private ethereum blockchain hosted locally?

Tags: android, web3js, go-ethereum

Since the localhost of running geth instance is 127.0.0.1 and that of emulator is 10.0.2.2. , how can I establish a connection between them??

Comment: You just answered your own question. In the emulator connect to 10.0.2.2

Comment: Can I connect to the geth instance directly

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "directly". Connecting to 10.0.2.2 in the emulator is the same thing as connecting to 127.0.0.1 on the host machine. If you have some java code that is able to connect to geth on 127.0.0.1 when executed on your computer, the same code should work on Android when run in emulator on said machine. All you need to do is replace the ip with 10.0.2.2